# Ok to use initializer lists to initialize windows api structures?

Tags: c++, winapi, initialization, structure

Is it a bad practice to not explicitly set the values of each member of a structure, for example in CHARFORMAT structure, you can declare initialize it all in one line like this:

```
 CHARFORMAT foo = {sizeof(CHARFORMAT),CFM_FACE,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Arial"};
```

I especially like doing it this way because not only is that a lot less typing but I don't have to call _tcscpy or something similar to copy into the string value of the szFaceName. I'm not sure if this is faster, and I don't care if it is or not, and I don't plan on ever porting or changing compilers, SDK libraries or anything.

All I want to know is, could there be repercussions from doing the init this way? And if so, are the risks involved just plain not worth the trouble? Should I avoid initializing structs this way all together and just do it explicitly?

Comment: Footnote: currently I am using this compiler/linker:

Comment: Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12.00.8168
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 6.00.8168
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 6.00.8168
IDE: notepad2.exe and msdev.exe (visual C++ 6.0) 
(all for 80x86)

Comment: Does this even compile??

Comment: Technically it might work, but it is a lot harder to see what fields you are actually initializing. Source code should be optimized for reading, not writing.

Comment: Also, about planning for the future: Some of us wrote programs in the 1980's and explicitly didn't care about the year 2000 - the programs wouldn't be around that long anyway. Guess what!

Comment: This is just fine, initializing a char[] from a literal is supported by the language.  Do consider joining the 21st century.  Upgrade your 14 year old compiler and start using Unicode.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't do it because it's error-prone and unreadable.  If the code needs to be adjusted, it's too easy to accidentally insert or to remove an initializer (or to replace the wrong one).

Note that you can avoid some of the typing by letting the compiler zero-initialize most members for you:

```
CHARFORMAT foo = { 0 };
foo.cbSize = sizeof foo;
foo.dwMask = CEM_FACE;
_tcscpy_s(foo.szFaceName, _countof(foo.szFaceName), T("Arial"));
```

Unfortunately, there's no avoiding the `strcpy` call (especially since the Microsoft compiler does not support C99 designated initializers).

Comment: First I upvoted you for essentially the correct thing, then I was forced to downvote you. tscpy? T()? Did you teleport here from 1990?

Comment: @Puppy Wow, you downvoted me for that?  That's kind of petty.  Is there anything actually *wrong* with my answer?  The character type has no relevance to the question, and the OP was already using non-wide strings, so I was nudging toward a transition to UTF-16.  Jeez.